# How to zoom into a Java app under KDE4?

Tags: kde, java

I have 200 dpi monitor and this Java is just inscrutinable app small. The desktop zoom effect is cool -- but it doesn't seem permanent? I would like to, basically, change every pixel into 2x2 pixels or 3x3 even.

Comment: Where on earth do they sell 200 dpi monitors?

Comment: The "Big Bertha" IBM T221 is sold on IBM eBay and Yahoo! Japan at least. I got mine from the latter via a proxy site, there are ton of sites that let you bit on japanese auctions. Way, way, way cheaper than on Ebay.

Comment: Just curious: What major benefit do you get from such high resolution?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo Xft.dpi: 200 | xrdb -load -
```

Does that help?

If so, you can see if your desktop environment automatically merges `~/.Xresources` or similar at startup, and place that there.

Comment: Not at home but I would be surprised if it would, Xft is just font size. I have DisplaySize 487 304 in xorg.conf anyways.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `xrandr` to change the resolution of your desktop.  if you cut your resolution by half, that will have the same effect as doubling the pixel size.

`xrandr` is the X-Windows Resize And Rotate tool.

running it with no options will give you the list of supported resolutions:

```
bash-$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1440 x 878, maximum 1440 x 900
default connected 1440x878+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1440x900       60.0      2.0  
   1152x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1024x640       60.0  
   1280x800       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   800x500        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x480        60.0  
   1344x840       60.0  
   1440x878        1.0*
```

You can use it to change to one of the supported resolutions by passing the new size:

```
bash-$ xrandr --size 800x600
```

I don't know of any way to force a single application, or a single X window to be displayed at a different resolution than the root window, though.

You can use the `xdpyinfo` command to see if your display support dynamic resizing.
Run it with no arguments, and you're looking to see if the `RANDR` extension is there:

```
bash-$ xdpyinfo | more
<snip some stuff>
number of extensions:    23
    Apple-DRI
    Apple-WM
    BIG-REQUESTS
    DAMAGE
    DOUBLE-BUFFER
    GLX
    Generic Event Extension
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    MIT-SHM
    RANDR
    RENDER
    SECURITY
    SGI-GLX
    SHAPE
    SYNC
    X-Resource
    XC-MISC
    XFIXES
    XINERAMA
    XINERAMA
    XInputExtension
    XKEYBOARD
    XVideo
<snip>
```

If you see `RANDR` in that list, then your display supports using `xrandr`.  You may need to install the package that provides `xrandr`, and which package that is and how to install it would depend on what distro/OS you are using.

Comment: This is not per app.